# После переноса скрипта на хостинг не видит библиотеку

Tags: python, python-3.x, hosting

[image]

Я много раз запуска скрипт в Pycharm и он отлично работал,но после переноса скрипта на хостинг он стал требовать Jconfig который естественно был установлен и подключен,эта ошибка была не на одном хостинге.На картинке видно что я установил Jconfig под питон,и сразу запустил скрипт,но питон все равно не видит Jconfig,помогите!

Comment: Вам нужно проверить пути поиска модулей. Но я рекомендую создать виртуальное окружение (не забудьте активировать) и работать уже в нём, это исключит сразу множество ошибок.

Comment: Так ты импортируешь `import jconfig`, а в описании пакета на PyPI стоит, что надо импортировать `from JConfig.config import JConfig`. Или тебе нужен модуль `jconfig` из пакета `vk-api`? Тогда его и надо устанавливать, `pip install vk-api`.